# How do I join the College of Winterhold when Faralda just keeps asking me to shout

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have to get into the college for the main quest, but I have no magical ability on this character so to get her to let me in I told her I was the Dragonborn. She told me to show her the voice. I keep shouting, but she just keeps telling me the same thing over and over, I can't even talk to her, she just keeps telling me to shout when I select her.

Something worth noting is that she's not in her normal spot. When I started talking to her she was, but as soon as she asked me to shout and the conversation ended, she ran to the inn and went inside. Now she's standing in the inn next to the door just telling me to shout over and over again.

http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/864966217805571753/0516596C19CAE0D5420F3C1E72CF0604E345DA88/

Comment: Sounds like a bug =/

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck. I might have to use the console to move myself through the gate.

Comment: have you shouted AT her?

Comment: Yes, and she killed me for it.

Comment: Hm... If i remember correctly she asks you on the bridge to the college. The only thing I could think of is to shout where she 'should' be and see what happens

Comment: I found out what happened. I have a mod installed that makes citizens run inside during a vampire attack. I didn't know it, but there was a vampire attack. When I left the inn, a vampire attacked and after I killed it, Faralda left the inn and walked back to her spot. Once she's back to her spot, just shout and she'll walk you across the bridge and let you into the college. First to put that in an answer gets it accepted ;p

Comment: Now I know why those three people were just standing next to the door not doing anything =S

Comment: You can answer your own questions here, and you should when you figure it out yourself. Just post that. You can mark it accepted after (I believe) a day. (And you get a badge for self-answering.)

Comment: Yeah but I don't get any points for answering myself. I've done it several times on StackOverflow. Why answer my own question when I can give someone else the 15 points?

Comment: You'll get points for any upvotes on your answer (like mine).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out what was happening. I have the [When Vampires Attack](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=114273579) mod installed, which makes citizens run inside during a vampire attack. A vampire just happened to spawn in town during my conversation with Faralda, so as soon as the conversation ended, she ran inside the nearest public building (the inn). That's why two other people were also standing near the door. As soon as I left the inn and killed the vampire Faralda went back to her spot. Once she got there a simple 'Fus' aimed at the sky made her take me to the College.

Comment: I believe you shoul mark this as accepted answer, as long as you managed to find a solution for you problem.

Answer (score 7):

Judging by your screenshot, you've got a mod or two installed. Try disabling/removing these mods, they might be causing this bug. Faralda is normally standing on the bridge to the College when she asks you to show her your shout, could be a location-based bug.

Comment: I have almost two hundred mods, going through that process would have taken a few hours =p

Comment: That was an exaggeration, I actually have like 211 mod files in my data folder, probably around 120 mods. And because Skyrim is an incredible game now. I'm on my 4th character, almost 2000 hours of gameplay. Mods make Skyrim an entirely new and immensely better game.

Comment: I agree that mods make it better. Does that many mods really have no affect on performance, or conflict with each other?

Comment: Not when you know what you're doing. I make custom mod packs and my own scripted installers. I keep everything neat and when a mod does something that would cause I problem I fix it myself.

Comment: As for performance hits, if you have a 1GB VRAM card, you might not be able to do all the texture packs, but if you have a 2GB VRAM card like me, you can install all the super high-res texture packs you want with no performance loss at all. The only thing that affects my performance at all, really, is my ENB. Which I tweaked to the perfect setting myself. It's based on the Cinematic Fantasy ENB, which is a lighter ENB than most of them anyway. So it doesn't affect my performance too much. I get 60 fps most of the time.